# Regex not matching letter followed by digits

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to match strings that starts with a letter followed by 2,6 digits anywhere in the line using the following regex ,the following regex matches R77 but not J123, can anyone provide guidance on how to fix this?

import re

```
code_free = "[KG6.R77.1.2][J123-P1A-00194]/12C114"
o = re.search(r'(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9:])([a-zA-Z](\d{2,6}[a-zA-Z]?|\d{1}[xX]{1,2}))([^a-zA-Z0-9]|AP|DEV|$)', code_free)

print (o.group(2))
```

Comment: It does match https://regex101.com/r/DX3W2m/1 but you have to find all matches instead of only 1 using re.search

Comment: Your requirements are not clear: you say "*starts with a letter followed by 2,6 digits anywhere in the line*", but there are many more conditions in the pattern itself, e.g. there should be no `:` before the first letter, there can be a digit followed with one or two `x`/`X` instead of the 2-6 digits... What is true and what is not?

Comment: So `A1234567` would _not_ be a match?

Comment: yes,A1234567 would not be a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use with `re.findall`:

```py
(?<![a-zA-Z0-9:])([a-zA-Z](?:\d{2,6}[a-zA-Z]?|\d[xX]{1,2}))(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]|AP|DEV|$)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/mlewva/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z0-9:]             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                             'Z', '0' to '9', ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]                 any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d{2,6}                  digits (0-9) (between 2 and 6 times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-zA-Z]?                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                               'Z' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [xX]{1,2}                any character of: 'x', 'X' (between 1
                               and 2 times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^a-zA-Z0-9]             any character except: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                             'Z', '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AP                       'AP'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DEV                      'DEV'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: when looking ahead why do we have to do `(?=` ?

Comment: @wisecrack It is a positive lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, just use `re.findall` with the pattern `\b[A-Z]\d{2,6}\b`:

```
code_free = "[KG6.R77.1.2][J123-P1A-00194]/12C114"
codes = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]\d{2,6}\b', code_free)
print(codes)  # ['R77', 'J123']
```